# Keeping track of selected div in grid of divs with React state

Tags: arrays, reactjs, grid

I am new to React/JS and have been trying for a few days to figure out how to keep track of which **Collection** below is selected.

I want the user to be able to click on the `collection` div and trigger the **selected** badge (commented out in the code, but I've included it in the screenshots) for that specific collection div. Upon clicking on a new div, the original div should have the badge remove and the newly clicked upon div should have the new badge. In other words, only one collection should have the badge at any point in time. I want to keep track of this in the `Collection` component's `state` (unless there is a better way).

For more reference, each `collection` div is a card that is highlighted upon hover. The site is also deployed at https://gatsby-client.rishipr.now.sh/practice.

[image: CollectionList]

**Collection.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react"

class Collection extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="collection">
        <div className="collection-name">
          {this.props.name}{" "}
          {/* <span className="collection-selected-badge">SELECTED</span> */}
        </div>
        <div className="collection-description">{this.props.description}</div>
        <div className="collection-description">
          {this.props.numQuestions} questions
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Collection
```

**CollectionList.js**

```
import React from "react"
import Collection from "./collection"

const CollectionList = props => {
  return (
    <div className="collections">
      <Collection
        name="All Questions"
        description="All questions (technical & behavioral)"
        numQuestions="400"
      />
      <Collection
        name="Top Behavioral"
        description="The most common behavioral questions to prepare for"
        numQuestions="21"
      />
      <Collection
        name="Outside the Guide"
        description="Questions from outside BIWS 400 and WSO"
        numQuestions="12"
      />
      <Collection
        name="20 Must Know Questions"
        description="The 20 must-know interview questions"
        numQuestions="20"
      />
      <Collection
        name="Real IB Interview Questions"
        description="Questions from real interviews at various banks"
        numQuestions="16"
      />
      <Collection
        name="Brain Teasers"
        description="Common brain teasers"
        numQuestions="4"
      />
    </div>
  )
}

export default CollectionList
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `state` to your `CollectionList` component, storing the name of the selected `Collection`:

```
const CollectionList = props => {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(null);
  return (
  // ...
  )
}
```

Pass the `selected` and `setSelected` props to all of your `Collection` component:

```
<Collection
  name="All Questions"
  description="All questions (technical & behavioral)"
  numQuestions="400"
  selected={selected}
  setSelected={setSelected}
/>
```

Add an `onClick` method to the outer `div` of your `Collection` component, which sets the `selected` state value to the `name` of the current `Collection`:

```
<div
  className="collection"
  onClick={() => this.props.setSelected(this.props.name)}
>
  // ...
</div>
```

Check if the `selected` prop is the same as the current collection's `name` in your `Collection` component. If true display the `selected badge`:

```
{this.props.selected === this.props.name && (
  <span className="collection-selected-badge">SELECTED</span>
)}
```

Here's a [codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/keeping-track-of-selected-div-in-grid-of-divs-with-react-state-jsp1s), though not as pretty as the image you provided.

Comment: Wow... thanks for the prompt and thorough response. This is awesome!